# Microphone input from speaker output

Tags: audio, microphone

I can find literally no information online on how to hook up the computer sound to the microphone. If that sounds confusing, here's a way of visualizing it:

Computer sound -> Computer plays the sound -> Microphone input directly -> Voice chat

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible. And there are tons of ways to do this on Windows, Linux, and OSX but I'll be covering Windows, as that's what I have experience with:

1. First option if you're running windows, is to use the [stereo mix virtual device](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/). Once it's enabled, set the microphone in discord/skype/telegram to "stereo mix."

> **Pros**: no additional software, quick setup, free.
> **Cons**: Can't talk at the same time, and other people in discord will be able to hear themselves. Have to change to and from the `stereo mix` device everytime you want to start/stop sharing your audio.

2. Use a Virtual Audio cable. There are a few different options out there, but they mostly all work the same, and this one is free: https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm To use this, set the `Line 1 (VB-Audio Cable)` as your microphone in discord, and then go to the `Stereo Mix` device properties and check the box `listen to this device` and set it to the virtual cable:
   [image]

> **Pros**: Minimal software, relatively simple setup, You can talk at the same time, less fiddling need to turn it 'on' or 'off'
> **Cons**: Other discord users will be able to hear themselves, still requires you go into windows sound control panel to turn it 'on/off'

3. Use [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm). (same developer of the virtual audio cable I included above). There are many setup videos for voicemeeter, setting it up to do exactly what you want without discord users being able to hear themselves. Here's one that I found at the top of my google video search for "voicemeeter guide": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_fk5SqktJg

> **Pros**: Incredibly flexible, Share arbitrary audio, audio effects, can be used for more than just sharing your audio, discord users can't hear themselves, very scalable free.
> **Cons**: Your audio setup is now reliant on voicemeeter (at least it's free), moderately complicated, it's easy to mess up the configuration.

4. Use [Synchronous Audio Router](http://sar.audio/). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4MfZdPii3c This is way more complicated than voicemeeter, though you can do so much more with it. I don't recommend going for this option unless you've run into limitations in voicemeeter. A similar software for OSX is [soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) or some implementations of [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/) for linux/unix (and sometimes windows).

> **Pros**: Nothing is impossible, audio setup is more flexible/powerful than what most streamers have, open-source, mostly free
> **Cons**: Incredibly complicated, not bug-free, lots of heavy software, easier to break than voicemeeter. Since it needs a Digital Audio Workstation (DAW) to be used, it's cost is whatever the supporting software/hardware is.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what ports you have on your computer, you could just use a cable from *line out* to *line in/microphone in*. Older computers usually had two 3.5 mm audio jacks. Newer ones have them combined in one 4-pin 3.5 mm headset jack. That could also work with the right cable/adapter combination. You also have to get the volume levels right.

Or you can do it with software like [Jack Audio](https://jackaudio.org/). This is a more flexible approach.